# How does the array property work in JS object

Tags: javascript

For the following code, why the `propB` of `myObj` is updated? And why `test.childObj` doesn't have the own property `propB`?

```js
var myObj = { propA: '', propB: [] }
var fatherObj = {
    childObj: null,
    init: function() {
        this.childObj = Object.create(myObj);
        this.childObj.propA = 'A';
        this.childObj.propB.push(2);
    }
}

var test = Object.create(fatherObj);
test.init();

console.log(myObj.propB.length);
console.log(test.childObj.hasOwnProperty('propA'));
console.log(test.childObj.hasOwnProperty('propB'));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `Object.create` you do not copy an object, but you create a new object that inherits the passed one:

```
  this.childObj { } ->  myObj { propA: "", propB: [] }
```

Now when you get a property, it gets looked up in the inheritance chain. As it can't be found in the child object, it gets looked up in `myObj`. That is usually not a problem, as setting an objects property directly sets it on the object itself without using the inheritance chain, therefore this:

```
  this.childObj.propA += "test";
```

looks up `propA` on `myObj` but sets `propA` on the `childObj`. With reference types however, you do not rewrite the property, therefore this:

```
  this.childObj.propB.push(1);
```

looks up `propB` in `myObj`, and pushes to that, the result is:

```
 this.childObj { propA: "test" } ->  myObj { propA: "", propB: [1] }
```

To resolve that, the childObj has to have its own `propB` array:

```
 this.childObj.propB = this.childObj.propB.slice();
```

That results in:

```
 this.childObj { propA: "test", propB: [1] } ->  myObj { propA: "", propB: [1] }
```

and now pushing to `propB` pushes to the array in `childObj`.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `myObj` becomes a prototype of newly created `test` object (caused by creating it via [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Due to you just modify underlying prop `propB` of `childObj` (and not assign the new value like for `propA`) you only modify the prop of prototype. Please read more about [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

By using `Object.create(myObj);`, `myObj` becomes the prototype of `childObj`. If a property is not found in an object and is found in the prototype, the one from the prototype is used. Also note that `hasOwnProperty` tells if the objects owns the property itself, and will return false if it exists only in the prototype and not in the object. By assigning directly a property on an object, you set it on the object, not on the prototype, but when you modify the property propB with push, the property is not found directly in childObject, so you modify the prototype.

You have to be careful with that, as all objects created this way will share the same prototype object and by modifying one, you will modify it for all instances.

You have also to be extra careful because it can be tricky to know in javascript where in the prototype chain your property come from, as myObj also have a prototype.

```js
var myObj = { propA: '', propB: [] }
var fatherObj = {
    childObj: null,
    init: function() {
        this.childObj = Object.create(myObj);
        this.childObj.propA = 'A';
        this.childObj.propB.push(2);
    }
}

var test = Object.create(fatherObj);
test.init();

console.log('test: ', test);
console.log('test prototype: ', test.__proto__);
console.log('test.childObj: ', test.childObj);
console.log('test.childObj prototype: ', test.childObj.__proto__);
console.log(test.childObj.hasOwnProperty('propA'));
console.log(test.childObj.hasOwnProperty('propB'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript inheritance does not work like in most other languages. When using `var x = Object.create(someObj)`, the new object `x` is actually empty (it has no properties of its own) along with a reference to its prototype: the separate object `someObj`.

Any **property** or **function** that you then try to access from `x` which does not resolve there, will be looked up in `someObj` - or even higher up, if `someObj` also has a prototype object, etc.

Things can get confusing when inherited properties are **modifiable objects**, as in your example. As we have seen, trying to modify the array `x.propB` by pushing an item to it, will actually modify the inherited array contained in `someObj`.

I'm strongly convinced that it is *bad style* to have modifiable objects (both arrays and regular objects) in prototype objects. Instead, prototype objects should contain **only functions** and **no data**, or at least no data beyond simple strings, numbers and booleans which are not modifiable.

To summarize:

- Functions are useful to inherit, they are not modifiable (you can't change the function body), and can still be overridden/replaced if needed.
- Data becomes shared data by all inheritors, unless/until they override it by a re-assignment, which is a burden in itself.